# How can a thread attempt to call the wait() method in a monitor it doesnt own the lock of (thus throwing IllegalMonitorStateException)

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, monitor

To my understanding, the thread needs to own the lock to even enter the synchronized block with the wait() call. How is it possible that it does so without owning the lock?

```
public synchronized void daten_ablegen(Client c) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Client " + c.ID + " will Daten ablegen");

        while (sicherungswunsch || (anzahlClients >= maxClients)) {
            System.out.println(c.ID + " sleeps.");
            c.wait();
        }

        anzahlClients++;

        System.out.println(anzahlClients + " Clients legen Daten ab.");
    }
```

The above code throws IllegalMonitorStateException when more than one thread tries to call daten_ablegen(). However I would expect a thread to either not enter the method or enter it WITH the lock acquired and then successfully go to sleep.

(I can post the entire project that is my homework, I just dont want to add unecessary stuff)

Comment: Not the same lock - in your example you'd want to invoke `wait()` (on the `this` object) since that is what the `synchronized` is locking.  And where is the notify - presumably somewhere in same class where `anzahlClients` is decremented?

Comment: @Gardener yes, the notify comes later. Your solution worked, thanks a lot. I didnt consider that invoking 'wait()' on the client would apply to the lock of the client, not the lock of Server (the class where the above code is in). Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

As @Gardener pointed out in the comments, calling `wait()` on the client doesn't work in this case, since the lock the thread would hold in that moment belongs to the Server object (the class the above code is in), not the client. That explains why the `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.